# Raster series sum

Tags: r

I have a loop with a series of raster images and I want to extract the values ​​equal to 150 and then add the total amount of pixels for the entire length of the loop. With the code that I have only managed to get the total values ​​for each image separately and not in total form. Thanks

```
   m=52419 #total pixels basin
   for(i in 1:4){
   b1<-raster(myras1[i])
   bc = b1 == 150 #Values eq 150
   nbc = cellStats(bc,stat="sum")
   print(nbc)
   [1] 34962
   [1] 38729
   [1] 52389
   [1] 52176
   pc=nbc*100/m
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is recommended not to use loops in R for things that can be easily vectorised.  Rather than trying to fix the (several) problems with your loop, I show instead a better way. You can perform the whole calculation in a single vectorised line:

```
sum(cellStats(myras1==150, stat="sum")) * 100/m
```

Breaking this down: `cellStats` performed on a raster stack will return a vector of values, one for each layer.  `sum` then adds these together.  Then we divide by number of cells in the whole stack (all layers combined) and multiply by 100 to convert to a percnetage.

Testing this on some reproducible dummy test data:

```
set.seed(123)
myras1 = list(
  raster(nrows = 100, ncols = 100, vals = sample(140:150,10000,T)),
  raster(nrows = 100, ncols = 100, vals = sample(140:150,10000,T)),
  raster(nrows = 100, ncols = 100, vals = sample(140:150,10000,T)),
  raster(nrows = 100, ncols = 100, vals = sample(140:150,10000,T))
)
myras1 = stack(myras1)
m = ncol(myras1) * nrow(myras1) * nlayers(myras1)

sum(cellStats(myras1==150, stat="sum")) * 100/m
# [1] 8.815
```

Comment: It works fine but with 5000 layers it sticks too much, is there any way to make it faster? Thanks

Comment: Calculation on very large stacks is always going to be slow. I don't know how you'll get much of a speed boost. Perhaps using a raster brick rather than stack will give some improvement. Is it not possible to run this as a batch operation and come back when its done? For best speed you might use FORTRAN rather than R for this, but the investment in development time will probably take you much longer than just waiting for R to churn out the result. Or you could buy some multi-core time on a cloud computing platform to run the calculation for you. Cloud computing is reasonably priced these days.